# Custom radio button: Why isn't this displaying the image?

Tags: html, css

I am a rank amateur at CSS, so this may be a stupid question, but why aren't the images for these custom buttons working?  The radio buttons themselves work just fine, but the images don't load.

I tried eliminating the text string after the ampersand, and the image loads just fine, but not surprisingly it no longer functions as a radio button when I do that.  Apache2 reports "unable to stat" errors, so this looks like a server-side error.

Relay.cgi:

```
#! /bin/bash
. /usr/lib/cgi-bin/relay/header.cgi
RunTest=$( $DIR/runtest )
if [[ $RunTest -eq 1 ]]
then
    nohup $DIR/Status.cgi
    exit
fi
cat $DIR/header.html
echo '</HEAD>'

echo '<BODY style="background-color:#00EE66">'
echo '<table>'
echo '<tr><h1><b>Aquarium Equipment Suspend</b></h1></tr>'
echo '<form action="/cgi-bin/relay/Timer.cgi">'
echo '<h2>'
echo '<p><b>'
echo '<tr>'
i=1
while read line
do
    echo '<tr>'
    echo '<th>'$line'</th>'
    echo '<th><input type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="15">'
    echo '<img src="/images/Button.png"></th>'  <=== Removed text for testing.  Image loads.
    echo '<th><input type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="30">'
    echo '<img src="/images/Button.png&text=30 Minutes"></th>'  <=== Radio button works.  Image does not load.
    echo '<th><input type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="60">'
    echo '<img src="Button.png&text=60 Minutes"></th>'
    echo '<th><input type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="120">'
    echo '<img src="Button.png&text=120 Minutes"></th>'
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done < $DIR/Relays.fil
echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit">'
echo '</b></p>'
echo '</form>'
echo '</h2>'
echo '</table>'
echo '</BODY>'
echo '</HTML>'
```

header.html:

```
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Aquarium Relay Control </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Leslie Rhorer">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
<STYLE>
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + img {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Apache2/errorlog:

```
[Fri Jun 07 13:28:29.299318 2019] [cgid:error] [pid 21675:tid 1946154032] [client 192.168.1.121:51888] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/relay/Button.png&text=60 Minutes, referer: http://192.168.1.40/cgi-bin/relay/index.cgi
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using to generate the images by passing a querystring, but if you want a space, usually it is safest to urlencode with '%20', so it should be `Button.png&text=60%20Minutes`. Also, not positive this is your issue, but you never close out your style tag in header.html - you are missing the end `</style>` tag.

Comment: I tried using the %20 tag, and it made no difference.  I do have the </style> closing tag.  I just did not show it here.

Comment: Oh, and I am not passing a querystring.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. You probably should be - again, not sure what you are using to serve images, but it looks like the same syntax as [placeholder.com](https://placeholder.com/), which would require `Button.png?text=60%20Minutes`. Also, I just noticed that your first two buttons use the src path starting with `/images/Button.png`, while the next two, and the first that fails, just starts with `Button.png`. Could either of those be the issue?

Comment: I am not sure of your question, "what you are using to serve images" means.  It's apache2, the same server that provides the web page.  The variable paths are meant to show they are all failing.  Removing "&..." allows the image to be served, but then it is no longer a radio button.  This has nothing to do with the space in the text.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below works.  The errors had nothing to do with formatting or the CSS code directly, and nothing to do with the validity (or lack thereof) of the HTML code.  The problem was that each "for" and "id" must be unique.  By adding the line number to each "for" and "id" field, the script now generates 63 unique values for the various buttons instead of only 7.
<s>Nothing I tried would allow the script to work using the above method, whether the page is produced from a Python script or a raw HTML script.  I have no idea why it does not work.  I have gotten a partial solution using a completely different method.  Only the first row (where i=1) works properly, but the display is correct and the entire first row does work.  Someone else will need to explain why the other rows (where i>1) don't work, although they do display properly.  The GET values are updated by selecting items in rows 2 - 6, but they are values correlating to row 1 ("R1"), rather than the other rows ("R2", R3, etc.).  I suspect it has something to do with the "for=" and / or "id=", but I have no idea what those do, so I have no way to know what to change.</s>

header.html

```
<STYLE>
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
}
.button15{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button15.png);}
.button30{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button30.png);}
.button45{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button45.png);}
.button60{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button60.png);}
.button90{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button90.png);}
.button120{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/Button120.png);}

.cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
    -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
    filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
...
</STYLE>
```

relay.cgi

```
#! /bin/bash
. /usr/lib/cgi-bin/relay/header.cgi
cat $DIR/header.html
echo '</HEAD>'

echo '<BODY style="background-color:#00EE66">'
echo '<form action="/cgi-bin/relay/Timer.cgi">'
echo '<table>'
echo '<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th>'
echo '<th>Aquarium Equipment Suspend</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>'
echo '<tr></tr>'
i=1
while read line
do
    echo '<tr>'
    echo '<th>'$line'</th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-'$i'" type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="15" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button15" for="button15-'$i'"></label></div></th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-'$i'" type="radio"     name="R'$i'" value="30" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button30" for="button30-'$i'"></label></div></th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-'$i'" type="radio"     name="R'$i'" value="45" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button45" for="button45-"></label></div></th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-'$i'" type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="60" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button60" for="button60-'$i'"></label></div></th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-'$i'" type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="90" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button90" for="button90-'$i'"></label></div></th>'
    echo '<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-'$i'" type="radio" name="R'$i'" value="120" />'
    echo '<label class="drinkcard-cc button120" for="button120-'$i'"></label></div></th>'
    echo</tr>
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done < $DIR/Relays.fil
...
</table>
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
...
```

Comment: When creating HTML there are certain rules to follow but because of how forgiving it is people will disregard or never realize that they have invalid HTML because it doesn't always manifest problems. Tables have pretty strict rules.  1. `<table>` tags can only have the following tags as **direct descendants** (ie child): `<col>`, `<colgroup>`, `<caption>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`. There's an exception to this rule in that it's ok to place `<tr>` directly nested within a `<table>` because all browsers will correct that by inserting a `<tbody>` as the child of `<table>` and ...

Comment: `[continued]`...`<tr>` moved into the `<tbody>`. 2. `<table>` (as previously explained), `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>` are the only tags that are allowed to have `<tr>` as a child. 3. Only `<tr>` can have `<td>` and `<th>` as children. This is a strict hierarchy that ***must be adhered to*** otherwise formatting, layout, and styling are unstable and results unpredictable.  Also, the `<table>` tag isn't completed...`</table>` missing end tag and `</form>` should be completely outside of `<table>`.

Comment: `[continued]` ...All of the garbage in the beginning of the `<table>` is invalid -- a `<tr>` must have `<th>` and `<td>` as children. `for` and `id` looks properly done. Be aware that if a group of radio buttons have the same name then there can only be one of them active at any given time. I'm assuming `name="R'$i'` assigns the same name. So if looking to either collect all values at once or all values of buttons that were clicked -- change radios into checkboxes and assign unique names to each of them -- or if you don't mine an array of values then keep the names identical.

Comment: Finally, as I suspected, it was indeed the "for=" and "id=" fields that were the remaining issue.  As my research later showed, the for and id tags must match for any given display pair, but they must be unique between different groups of radio buttons.  I fixed this issue above by adding the variable $i to the value of each "for=" and "id=" fields.  Now not only do all 42 fields display properly, but the selected value, if any, for each of the six rows is properly forwarded with the GET.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table I can't believe you'd think anything contrairy to what I have just said. Go to that link  then look at the blue section you'll see "permitted content". For= id pairs are unique only because id must be unique also you can have multiple labels associated to the same id. This association merely allows the user interaction to extend to the label so if clicked the input is clicked as well and vice versa. So after your "research" you have yet to get it correctly. If your code works it is not because of what you believe it be.

Comment: *"OF COURSE only one radio button of a group of radio buttons (defined by the name) is active at a given time. That is the definition of a radio button. Each row of seven radio buttons in this case has a unique name - a fact you missed."* LOL rightly so and if you knew what you were talking about you'd realize that if 7 radios have a unique name then they ***do not behave*** in the way you have just eloquently stated. So either you have a ton of semi-useless radios that behave individually or you have normal behavior for each group and you don't have unique names.

Comment: I can assume that each ECHO will increment `$i` by 1? Or is it by loop? So by that logic your names are all identical if by loop or -- if by ECHO then everything is unique and label and input have no association.

Comment: I said nothing about requiring I only said what was **VALID** which your code is obviously not even close. I'm not familiar with that language and you can't expect people that are generous enough to help to be prepared to understand when you haven't posted the proper tags. It's ok to admit that you don't know something try to be honest and not argumentative with those trying to help -- especially when you solicited for said help. Anyways good luck with whatever your endeavor may be and remember you asked for help and progressed toward a solution that I doubt you would've found without asking.

Answer (score 0):

OK, enough about my poor coding.  For completeness, here is the output of the script, after removing the cgi header.  It validates with no errors.  Note the values of "id=" and "for=", which were the issue with the original script.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Aquarium Relay Control </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Leslie Rhorer">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">    
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Aquarium Relay">
<META charset="utf-8"/>
<STYLE>
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
   appearance:none;
}
.button15{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button15.png);}
.button30{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button30.png);}
.button45{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button45.png);}
.button60{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button60.png);}
.button90{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button90.png);}
.button120{background-image:url(http://192.168.1.40/images/button120.png);}

.cc-selector input:active +.button-cc{opacity: .9;}
.cc-selector input:checked +.button-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;   
  -moz-filter: none;   
   filter: none;   
}
.button-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;

    width:100px;height:50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
   transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
   filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

TABLE, TH, TD {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
TABLE {
    width: 90%;
}
TH {
    height: 50px;
}

div.Countdown {  
    position: fixed;
    top: 26px;
    left: 480px;
    width: 300px;
    font: bold 24px Arial;
    color: black;
}
h1 {text-align: center;}
.tab { text-indent:30% }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="background-color:#00EE66">
<form action="/cgi-bin/relay/timer.cgi">
<h1>Aquarium Equipment Suspend</h1>
<p class="tab"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
<table><tr>
<th>Sump Equipment</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-1"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-1"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-1"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-1"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-1"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-1" type="radio" name="R1" value="120" />   
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-1"></label></div></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Protein Skimmer</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-2"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-2"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-2"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-2"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-2"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-2" type="radio" name="R2" value="120" />   
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-2"></label></div></th></tr>  
<tr>   
<th>Air Pump</th>    
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-3"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-3"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-3"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-3"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-3"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-3" type="radio" name="R3" value="120" />
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-3"></label></div></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Power Filter</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-4"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-4"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-4"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-4"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-4"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-4" type="radio" name="R4" value="120" />   
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-4"></label></div></th></tr>  
<tr>
<th>Power Heads Left</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-5"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-5"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-5"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-5"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-5"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-5" type="radio" name="R5" value="120" />
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-5"></label></div></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Power Heads Right</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-6"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-6"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-6"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-6"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-6"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-6" type="radio" name="R6" value="120" />   
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-6"></label></div></th></tr>  
<tr>
<th>Power Heads Center</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-7"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-7"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-7"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-7"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-7"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-7" type="radio" name="R7" value="120" />   
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-7"></label></div></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Spare</th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button15-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="15" />
<label class="button-cc button15" for="button15-8"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button30-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="30" />
<label class="button-cc button30" for="button30-8"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button45-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="45" />
<label class="button-cc button45" for="button45-8"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button60-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="60" />
<label class="button-cc button60" for="button60-8"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button90-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="90" />
<label class="button-cc button90" for="button90-8"></label></div></th>
<th><div class="cc-selector"><input id="button120-8" type="radio" name="R8" value="120" />
<label class="button-cc button120" for="button120-8"></label></div></th></tr>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```